# How do I get Flatpak programs to show in applications menu?

Tags: applications, flatpak

I went on Flathub to install VSCode and but it doesn't show up on applications menu. I used `flatpak list` and it shows that VSCode has been installed. How do I get programs installed through Flatpak to show in the applications menu for quick access?

Comment: Did you install it by downloading the com.visualstudio.code.flatpakref file and double clicking it or using the flatpak CLI? The recommended method is the first. Did you try rebooting your computer? You can try uninstalling it with the flatpak uninstall command and reinstalling from the flatpakref file and see if it solves it. I use VSCode and installed it as a flatpak and it shows up in my menu so something must have went wrong with the install.

Comment: Oh wow I rebooted and it shows up now. Thanks. This brings me back to using Windows.

Comment: This is what I was supposed to advice you - to reboot. Can you add an answer of your question with the way it was resolved and later accept it as the right one?